# guard-minitest + spring not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, guard, minitest, rails-spring

I have a rails 4.0.2 project and I'm using guard 4.7.5, guard-minitest 2.2.0, and spring 1.1.0.

When my Guardfile reads:

```
guard :minitest, spring: true do
  …
end
```

I get spring usage info when running guard.

As per the guard-minitest [README](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/blob/master/README.md), if my Guardfile reads:

```
guard :minitest, spring: 'rake test' do
  …
end
```

it runs all the default tests (see `rake -T`).

In fact, when running `rake test` by itself, it doesn't matter what I type afterwards, it *always* runs the default tests. Running `bundle exec rake test [whatever]` produces the same results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

```
guard :minitest, spring: 'rake test' do
  …
end
```

Works on my setup (i.e., it runs just the right tests), though it doesn't show detailed stats in the notifier (just passing/not passing).

Do you have the right watchers in your do block?
I'm basically using what `guard init` gave me, but I've uncommented the watchers under Rails 4, commenting out the rest. My complete `minitest` do block:

```
guard :minitest, spring: 'rake test' do

   #Rails 4
   watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                               { |m| "test/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
   watch(%r{^app/controllers/application_controller\.rb$}) { 'test/controllers' }
   watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_controller\.rb$})        { |m| "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
   watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)_mailer/.+})                   { |m| "test/mailers/#{m[1]}_mailer_test.rb" }
   watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                               { |m| "test/lib/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
   watch(%r{^test/.+_test\.rb$})
   watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$}) { 'test' }

end
```

**I'm using:**

- ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
- guard-minitest-2.2.0
- Guard version 2.6.0
- Spring version 1.1.2
- Rails 4.1.0
- Minitest-5.5.5

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 4.1.6, it seems to work out of the box. I just added `spring: true` to my `Guardfile` and it worked. Correct tests are run when a file is modified and it does seem to start faster than without Spring.

My setup: Ruby 2.1, Rails 4.1.6, Guard 2.6.0, guard-minitest 2.3.2, Spring 1.1.3, minitest 5.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run bin\rake spring test?

If not, that's your problem as "spring: true" runs bin\rake.